# SQL - Get a pair of rows depending on the sum of values from a column

Tags: sql, sum, max

My table looks something like this:

```
+------+------+-------+------+
| ColA | ColB | ColC  | ColD |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 10217 | 5    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 10217 | 6    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 10417 | 7    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 10417 | 8    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 2    | 1    | 10417 | 9    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 2    | 2    | 10417 | 10   |
+------+------+-------+------+
```

How do I write a query that would return a pair of rows with the following requirements:

1. After inputting a ColA value and a ColC range as parameters

   e.g. `ColA:  1      ColC: 10217 to 10417`

The table should look like this:

```
+------+------+-------+------+
| ColA | ColB | ColC  | ColD |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 10217 | 5    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 10217 | 6    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 10417 | 7    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 10417 | 8    |
+------+------+-------+------+
```

2. Now add the ColD values for each ColB pairings for the specific ColC values. Using my example, For ColC value `10217`, it would be `5 + 6` and ColC value `10417` would be `7 + 8`.
3. Then get the max between the two sums. So it would be 15 > 11.
4. Lastly, return the row pairings that resulted from getting the max above, which is 15.

The end result should look like this:

```
+------+------+-------+------+
| ColA | ColB | ColC  | ColD |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 10417 | 7    |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 10417 | 8    |
+------+------+-------+------+
```

I've only gotten to the part where I get the max. I've had trouble trying to get the row pairings.

```
SELECT Max(sumD) AS maxSumD
FROM (SELECT t1.ColA, t1.ColB, sum(ColD) AS sumD 
        FROM (SELECT * 
                FROM Table1 
                WHERE (ColA = paramA) and (ColC between paramFromC and paramToC))  AS t1 
        GROUP BY t1.ColA, t1.ColB)
```

**SOLUTION**: Using Ctznkane's answer, I found this (hacky) solution:

```
SELECT TOP 2 SUMMEDVALUE, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
FROM (SELECT A.ColA, A.ColB, A.ColC, A.ColD, (A.ColD+B.ColD) as SUMMEDVALUE
      FROM Table1 A
      INNER JOIN Table1 B 
      ON A.ColA=B.ColA AND A.ColC=B.ColC AND t1.ColB<>t2.ColB) 
ORDER BY SUMMEDVALUE DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a pair of rows, then you should be joining the table with itself.

```
SELECT (A.COLD+B.COLD) SUMMEDVALUE, A.COLC, A.COLB, B.COLB, A.COLD, B.COLD
FROM TABLE1 A
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 B ON A.COLA=B.COLA AND A.COLC=B.COLC AND A.COLB<>B.COLB
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my post to include the solution I was able to find using your answer.